# How many different products can be formed by multiplying $n$ numbers at most once?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Let $a_1,\dots a_n$ be non-zero complex numbers. Products where each appears at most once (including $1$ for "empty product") will be
$$1,\ a_1,\ a_2,\dots a_n,\ a_1a_2,\ a_1a_3,\dots, a_{n-1}a_n,\dots, a_1a_2\dots a_n\,;$$
for the total of $2^n$ (number of subsets formed from $n$ elements). Of course, depending on $a_i$, not all products may be distinct, e.g. if $a_1=a_2=\dots =a_n=a$ we only get $n+1$ distinct products:
$$1,\ a,\ a^2,\dots,a^n.$$
This can be reduced further by assuming that $a^m=1$ for some $m\leq n$, and $a=1$ reduces the number to $1$. Making all $a_i$ equal is not the only way to get $n+1$, taking $a_2=a_1^{-1}$ also does it for $n=2$, say.

**Question:** it seems that if none of $a_i$ is a root of unity then $n+1$ is the lowest number. How does one prove that? Is the question of which numbers between $n+1$ and $2^n$ are realizable for some $a_i$ studied? Where can I read up on this?

The question is of interest in studying products $u_k=\prod_{i=1}^n(1-a_i^k)$, which represent the so-called [divisibility sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_sequence). Opening up the product turns it into a sum of powers with coefficients, and the number of distinct powers is the number discussed above. It will give the [recurrence order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) of the divisibility sequence.

Comment: Let me add a possibly useless piece of information.  $2^{n}$ is certainly realizable by picking the $a_i$'s to be distinct prime natural numbers.

Comment: I don't think I've seen the question of which numbers are attainable studied... is it even obvious there are numbers that cannot be attained below $2^n$?(lifting the conditions on the $a_i$ so that they may be $1$ or $0$)? Do we have an example of this?

Comment: In response to myself: the answer is no. I've added a proof to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$2$ proofs follow, one concerning the desired minimum number of products, the other regarding numbers which do not appear as the number of products.

**Proof 1**: An alternative proof via an algorithm.

Fix numbers $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ such that none are roots of unity, nor $0$. Call $C$ the set of products we've considered. Place $1$ in $C$, then for each $i$:

If $a_i \not \in C$: add $a_i$ to $C$.

Else: there exists some maximum positive integer $k$ such that $a_i^k \in C$, add $a_i \cdot a_i^k$ to $C$.

Return

The elements of $C$ are always distinct, as $a_i$ is only added if it is new, and $a_i^{k+1}$ cannot be in $C$ previously, as that would imply we've picked $k$ too small! (this also uses the fact that $a_i$ are not roots of unity nor $0$, hence $a_i^k$ are all distinct. An argument via their magnitude or angle in the complex plane suffices)

Note at the end of the algorithm, $|C| = n+1$ regardless of $a_i$ (providing they meet the base conditions). This is because we only add new elements to $C$ from either $a_i$ itself (which has not been previously considered), or $a_i$ times an element already in $C$ (which must have been formed from $a_j$ with $j < i$).

Of course one could add more elements to $C$ and get the entire desired list this way, but the above will always exist at a minimum.

**Proof 2**: Concerning the study of numbers that do *not* appear as the number of products of $n$ numbers - **there are no nontrivial such values**. Every value $v$ between $1$ and $2^n$ has a set of $n$ *positive integers* $a_i$ such that there are $v$ distinct values that can be formed by products of these $a_i$ (each used at most once). I'll use the notation $a(m,k,i)$ to denote the value of $a_i$ so that there are $m$ possible products using $k$ integers. The proof proceeds by induction.

First, the claim is easy to verify when $n=1$, as then the assignments $1$ and $2$ satisfy.

Now suppose for induction the claim is true for $n=k-1$. Note this implies that $a(m,k-1,i)$ exist and can be well defined for $m \in [1, 2^{k-1}]$. We know that all values in the interval $[1, 2^{k-1}]$ can be achieved by setting $a_k = 1$ and using $a_i = a(m, k-1, i)$ for the other values.

We consider the remaining values in $2$ categories, even and odd. We can get any even number $2m \leq 2^k$ by setting $a_i = a(m, k-1, i)$, and then picking $a_k$ to be a prime larger than any of the $a_i$ (or any number relatively prime to the others - it matters not how we pick it). Since $gcd(a_k, a_i) = 1$, it must be that $a_k \cdot p$ for any $p$ a product of the $a_i$ is new.

For any odd number $2m-1 < 2^n$ (and greater than $1$), we need only pick $a_i = a(m,k-1,i)$ and $$a_k = \max_{S \subset [k-1]} \prod_{i \in S} a_i,$$ in words: the largest number we could form from the first $k-1$ $a_i$. Note because our odd number is greater than $1$, $a_k \neq 1$. Therefore for all products $p$ $a_k \cdot p \geq a_k$, so all products that involve $a_k$ are new values, and since $a_k \cdot p = a_k \cdot p' \iff p = p'$, each of these is unique. Therefore we have $2m$ possible products ($p$ and $a_k \cdot p$), minus one as $a_k = \max_{S \subset [k-1]} \prod_{i \in S} a_i$ is already a possible product.

The case of $1$ is trivial, just set all $a_i = 1$.

Thus every number between $1$ and $2^n$ is a possible size for the set of distinct products. This can be generalized for every number between $n+1$ and $2^n$ without using $1$'s via noticing that the additional base cases $v = n+i$ can all be done using $a_i = 2$ for $i < n$, with $a_n = 2^i$, and using the same induction (which now no longer will have any $a_i$ being $1$'.

Comment: Since you proved they always exist is there an efficient algorithm to get n numbers with m distinct products for any n and m?

Comment: Following the induction suffices - start with $m$ mod $2$, find some $a_1$ that satisfies, then for $i \in [2, log(m)]$, find $a_i$ based on the binary representation of $m$, padding with $1$'s should you reach $m$. Takes $O(\max (\log m, n))$ time.

Comment: Thank you, this looks very comprehensive. What area does this kind of problem belong to? I am at a loss as to what literature to search for, it feels like a combination of combinatorics with group theory (finitely presented) or formal grammars, but I haven't seen something like that. Also, if $0,1$ (and roots of unity) are not allowed would then there be numbers between $n+1$ and $2^{n}$ that can't be realized (your construction seems to use $1$-s a lot, but maybe this is just for simplicity)?

Comment: @Conifold There are many niche problems mixing algebra and combinatorics, questions like how many representations are there of a group, or what is the expected length longest increasing subsequence of a list both appear in this grey area. I believe both are essentially from combinatorics though, just requiring the algebra, analysis, and so forth as it pertains to the specific problem. My guess would be to just get deeper in combinatorics. You should eventually see things from graph theory, linear algebra, and just about everywhere else.

Comment: @Conifold regarding removing $1$ from the construction, I can easily get everything between $2^{n-1}$ through $2^n$. The trouble is values like $6$ with $4$ elements. The induction no longer works because $m=3< 3+1$, which would be the previous case, and which we've proven can't be done. However, the choice $2,2,2,1/4$ seems to have $6$ products: $1/4, 1/2, 1, 2, 4, 8$, so maybe there's still hope. There are many many scaleable tricks. Perhaps this would make another good question? I'll do some playing.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\mathcal{P}:=\big\{\prod_{i\in S}\,a_i\,|\,S\subseteq\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\big\}$.  We claim that, if none of the $a_i$'s is zero or a primitive root of unity, then $|\mathcal{P}|\geq n+1$.  We shall instead prove a stronger statement that $|\mathcal{P}|\geq n+1$ and the equality holds if and only if there exists $a\neq 0$ such that $a_i\in\left\{a,\frac{1}{a}\right\}$ for each $i=1,2,\ldots,n$.

The proof is done by induction on $n$.  The base cases $n=1$ and $n=2$ are trivial.  Now suppose on the contrary that the claim $|\mathcal{P}|\geq n+1$ fails for some positive integer $n>2$.  By removing $a_n$ from the list, we obtain the set $\mathcal{P}'$ of products involving only $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{n-1}$.  By induction hypothesis, $|\mathcal{P}'|\geq n$.  Since $|\mathcal{P}|<n+1$, we conclude that $|\mathcal{P}|=n$, so $\mathcal{P}=\mathcal{P}'$.  By induction hypothesis, there exists $a\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ such that $a_i\in\left\{a,\frac{1}{a}\right\}$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,n-1$.  Thus, for some integer $m$ with $0\leq m\leq n$, we have
$$\mathcal{P}'=\left\{\frac{1}{a^m},\frac{1}{a^{m-1}},\ldots,a^{n-2-j},a^{n-1-m}\right\}\,.$$
Since $a_n\mathcal{P}'\subseteq\mathcal{P}=\mathcal{P}'$, $a_n=a^k$ for some $k\in\{-m,-m+1,\ldots,n-2-m,n-1-m\}=:T$.  Since $a_n$ is not a primitive root of unity, $k\neq0$.

If $k>0$, then $a_na^{n-1-m}=a^{n-1-m+k}\in\mathcal{P}'$, so $a_na^{n-1-m+k}=a^j$ for some $j\in T$.  That is, $a^{n-1-m+k-j}=1$.  We have $$n-1-m+k-j\geq n-m-j\geq 1\,.$$  Therefore, $a$ is a primitive root of unity, which is absurd.  Thus, $|\mathcal{P}|\geq n+1$ must hold.  On the other hand, if $k<0$, then $a_na^{-m}=a^l$ for some $l\in T$.  That is, $a^{l+m-k}=1$.  We have
$$l+m-k\geq l+m+1\geq 1\,.$$
Ergo, $a$ is again a primitive root of unity, which is a contradiction.

Now, suppose that $|\mathcal{P}|=n+1$.  Consider the set $\mathcal{P}'$ as before.  If $\left|\mathcal{P}'\right|=n+1$, then $\mathcal{P}'=\mathcal{P}$ and $a_n\mathcal{P}'=\mathcal{P}'$.  That is, $\mathcal{P}'$ is a geometric progression with common ratio $a_n$, but then $a_n^{n+1}=1$ must hold, which violates the requirement that $a_n$ not be a primitive root of unity.  Thus, $\left|\mathcal{P}'\right|=n$ must hold.  However, it is now an easy exercise, using the induction hypothesis, to show that there exists $a\neq 0$ such that $a_i\in\left\{a,\frac{1}{a}\right\}$ for each $i=1,2,\ldots,n$.

Comment: This is almost correct- The correct statement is that there exists $a$ such that $a_i = a^{\pm 1}$ for all. $1 \leq i \leq n$. (your mistakes are when you cite "trivial" and "an easy exercise").

Comment: @AlexZorn  Thanks.  The proof has been adjusted accordingly.